# How to develop in Wordpress with Docker?

Tags: wordpress, docker, wordpress-theming

I have a docker container with installed WP and I want to create a new custom theme for it, but I don't want to install wp on own machine. Can I develop a new theme only via Docker container?

**UDP:** 
I solved my problem in this way:

1) in docker-composer.yml in a `wordpress` field need create a field

```
volumes:
   - ./wordpress:/var/www/html
```

2) Create in your file system the directory `wordpress` and run `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up`. Files will be moved in your directory and you can work with them and see a result in `localhost`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to login into container (make sure it is running) using following command

```
#>docker exec -it <container-name-or-id> sh
```

After that you can edit and create themes inside this container.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! 
But I solved my problem in another way. You can see it above.